# Django: ManyToMany field with multiple fk fields

Tags: python, django

Here is a simplified version of my models (Django 1.9, if that matters):

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.StringField()

class Match(models.Model):
    player_1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="player_1")
    player_2 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name="player_2")
```

Is there any way to add a `player.matches` field to the model, which would query all matches where the player is `player_1` or `player_2`? Specifically, I want to do this to take advantage of [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to reduce n+1 queries when getting matches for each player

I know I can re-structure the database to support that, but would prefer not to.

Comment: I think player.player1.all() and player.player2.all() will collectively give you all matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be through a reverse query merge.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.StringField()

    def matches(self):
        return self.player_1.all() | self.player_2.all()
```

Comment: Perfect -- and it works with prefetch_related. Thanks a bunch!